# Error when running Windows Phone Emulator while Vmware virtual machine is already running?

Tags: mobile, windows-phone, vmware, virtualization, virtual-machine

I have a problem when I try to run a windows phone application, the emulator starts running but at the moment it starts to load, the virtual machine that i'm running separetely gives an error and shutsdown. I googled the issue and it seems that the emulator conflicts with other running virtual machines.  How to resolve this issue, I need both the vm and the emulator to run at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by installing vmware 7.1 instead of the one I had(6.5) and then I had to disable 3d acceleration on the virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not a supported scenario.

The emulator (for all intents and purposes) **IS** a virtual machine and is not supported to run in another virtual machine or alongside one.

If you must have the other virtual machine running at the same time you'll have to put one of them on a different host machine.